# Should link navigate to new page, or show different div?

Tags: php, javascript, html, navigation

Example in code:

**No page navigation:**

```
<body>
   <nav>
      // Navigation links to the parts of the site.
      // Clicking a link calls a javascript function to display the relevant <div>
   </nav>
   <section id="page1">
      // Page 1 content
   </section>
   <section id="page2">
      // Page 2 content
   </section>
</body>
```

**Page navigation:**

```
// Page1.php:
<body>
   <nav>
      // Navigation links to parts of the site.
      // Act as normal <a> tags, redirecting the browser to the new page
   </nav>
   <section>
      // Page1 content
   </section>
</body>

// Page2.php:
<body>
   <nav>
      // Navigation links to parts of the site.
      // Act as normal <a> tags, redirecting the browser to the new page
   </nav>
   <section>
      // Page2 content
   </section>
</body>
```

**Pros for link navigation:**

- The browser doesn't need to load the entire site all at once
- No javascript needed to use the site
- Provides direct URLs for easy navigation
- Seems like the standard thing to do

**Pros for javascript navigation:**

- For sites with heavy server-side scripting (like mine), minimizes page requests
- No need for the same code in different places (the `<nav>` element, for example). Creating a `echo_nav_html()` function in PHP is not a good solution, as it makes coding in an IDE environment annoying
- After initial load, site is superfast, as barely any new requests are sent to the server

Oh wise internets, any thoughts on this?

Or maybe more elegant solutions that provide the pros listed for javascript navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to do both.

Have valid links on the HREFs on your anchors, but include onClick actions that load the div and disable the progress to the HREF.

Read about **[graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system)** and **[progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)**.

There are lots of reasons to provide non-JavaScript code.  Not all browsers support JavaScript.  Lots of corporate networks still use ancient versions of IE that may behave unpredictably, or they may force configuration that disables JS entirely.

You want your site to be usable by everyone, but provide the best possible experience to those users who have the technology to support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a heavy dose of server side code (assuming that means dynamic content generation/population), I would probably use links to other pages as I can't imagine that loading all the content you could possibly access on the site on initial load is real resource efficient, especially assuming not every user will access ever section of the site.

You can still use javascript, but I'd only generate the content when it's actually requested; whether that be through an AJAX call (so the URL's being called there) or loading a new page. Seems kind of wasteful to me to load everything at run time...that's just me though.

Comment: You're missing the point - there are objects and classes I need on every page, like the `User` class, and loading the page once means I only have to run the necessary database queries and construction scripts once

Comment: That's how an application generally works; that's why you use objects so you can reuse code behind a simple interface. That constraint doesn't justify the waste that would be generated by issuing a single request for the entire content of your site though. If the objects you have to reuse are causing a lot overhead, it'd probably be good to re-evaluate those. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Not ungrateful, it's just that I'm not going to rewrite my classes in a hurry... thanks for your help